# iOS Compatible Encryption Software

Tags: ios, encryption, cloud-storage

This may be off-topic here - if it is, I'd ask a moderator to migrate it to where it should be.

I may not be necessarily asking for an application, moreover a process,  that can achieve the following:

I want an application that uploads all my photos to my preferred Cloud Service (Google Drive) in an encrypted manner - as in, I do not want my online copy of these images viewable without the need to decrypt them

The way I see it now is, I can set the photos on my iPhone to auto-sync, then create a batch script on my PC (that is tied to the same Google Account) to run over all the files and encrypt them.

I want to know if there is a "client side" native iOS application that can perform this on my behalf - price is of no concern.